# Slick Slider - Applying slick active class to <a> according to active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

Im trying to add 'slick active' class to an a tag when the slide has been dragged. The class is applied on click but cant work out how to apply it to the other!

Any help deciphering my code would be much appreciated!

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $slideshow = $(".slider").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 300,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        swipeToSlide: true,
        touchThreshold: 3,
        arrows: false
    });

    $('.links').on('click', 'a', function( e ) {
        var slideIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();

        $slideshow.slick( 'slickGoTo', parseInt( slideIndex ) );
        $('.links li a').removeClass('slick-current');
        $(this).addClass('slick-current');
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    $('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event,slick,i) {
        $('.links li a .slick-slide').removeClass('slick-current');
        $('.links li a .slick-slide').eq(i).addClass('slick-current');  
    });

    $('.links li a .slick-slide').eq(0).addClass('slick-current');  

});
```

HTML

```
 <div class="large-3 columns page-content-left">

      <ul class="links">
           <li><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">slide3</a></li>

      </ul>

 </div>

<div id="" class="large-9 columns page-content-right">                             
   <section class="slider" id="slider1">

      <div class="slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
      </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: According to http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ you have 3 arguments on `afterChange` event: `slick`, `currentSlide` and `nextSlide`. You are using event, slick and i. Maybe you're using some invalid data in `eq()`? I guess you have to do `$(currentSlide).addClass('slick-current')`, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the class `slick-initialized` to `links`.

We don't have your HTML but it should look something like this:

```
<div class="links slick-initialized">
  <li><a><span class="slick-slide">1</span></a></li>
  <li><a><span class="slick-slide">2</span></a></li>
  <li><a><span class="slick-slide">3</span></a></li>
</div>
```

## update

now that we have the HTML it's clear why you still have a problem.  You set the class with `$('.links li a .slick-slide')`. That matches my code from above, you, however, have a different structure.

```
      <ul class="links">
           <li><a href="#">slide1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">slide2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">slide3</a></li>
      </ul>
```

first you would have to change it to

```
  <ul class="links slick-initialized">
       <li><a href="#" class="slick-slide">slide1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="slick-slide">slide2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="slick-slide">slide3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

and second change the jquery to `$('.links li a.slick-slide')` (space removed between `a` and `.slick-slide`).

Comment: I added in my HTML there as well! But I tried adding the slick-initialized but with no luck.

Comment: @BenjiBaird it seems like the HTML structure and the jQuery selectors don't match. I added a bit of explanation in the answer.

Comment: @BenjiBaird Have you looked at my comment? Should be enough.

Comment: @arcs That worked well, got another issue with this though. The active class is only applying to the first slider... I have multiple sliders within tabs on one page. So the active class is applying to slide1 in tab1 but not any of the others! Any ideas?

Comment: @BenjiBaird yes, I do. the problem is the jquery `.eq(i)`, it selects the `i` within all the results. To get the `i` for each slider change the code to `$('.links li:nth-child('+ ++i +') a.slick-slide').addClass('slick-current')`.

Comment: @arcs Tried that there as well and Im still getting the same result! I made another question on here if you want to have a look, it has more of my code in it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695455/slick-slider-adding-active-class-to-first-a-in-currently-open-foundation-t

Comment: @BenjiBaird Ohh I see, you also got two sliders and they should work completely separate.  I'll give it a try